# Scanf not reading all numbers found in CSV in C

Tags: c, loops

I am trying to read a `CSV` file of integers and count their number. However, the code executes this while loop once.
When i change the format of the file so that each number is on a separate line and no commas are there, it works. Can someone tell me where is my mistake? How can i make the loop work for `CSV`?

```
while(scanf("%d", &otherNum)==1)
{
    count++;
    printf("%d", otherNum);
}
```

Comment: _read a CSV file of integers ?_ but `scanf("%d",&otherNum)` will read from `stdin` not from CSV file. better use `fscanf(fp,"%d,",&otherNum);` where `fp` points to your CSV file.

Comment: @achal : stdin can be redirected to a file...

Comment: yes @SergeBallesta but code OP shows in that it doesn't seem so. Any way that's not the issue.

Comment: `scanf` et alii are really *poor man's parsers*. You should only use them for quick and dirty development, or when you are sure that the format will be acceptable - but in that case do test the return value. To read a csv file, you really should use `fgets` to read **lines** and then `strtok` or `strcspn` if there are no quotation marks, or a decicated parser if commas or newlines can exists in quoted fields.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as "%d" hits a non-integer (comma, or any other character), it exits the while loop.

You will need to build the logic of parsing between "%d" and other characters inside of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Better use below codes

```
 char num[50];
 int otherNum = 0;

 FILE *f = fopen("yourCSV.csv", "w");

  while(fgets(num,sizeof num,f){
    if(num[0] != ',')
    {
        otherNum = atoi(num);
        printf("%d", otherNum);
    }

}
```

Comment: That addition skips white space. But what about commas or whatever separator is used in the CSV input?

Comment: @Jens, respect your advise. I have modified my answer.

Comment: `fscanf(f, " %s", num)` is akin to recommending the obsolete `gets()`.  Weak code due to its buffer overrun possibilities.  IAC the leading space in `" %s"` is not needed.

Comment: @chux, thanks for your advise. I have corrected the answer. :-)

Comment: @chux Any white space in a format skips any amount of white space in the input, so it is needed if columns contain white space or to eat newlines.

Comment: @jens "Any white space in a format skips any amount of white space in the input" is true (except when in a scanset). "so it is _needed_ if columns contain white space or to eat newlines" is not true. All specifiers, such as  `"%s"`,  except  `"%c"`,  `"%n"`,  `"%["`, consume leading white-space - even without a leading`" "`.  No great harm to have the space there.